# Android: Add rows in custom gridview based on certain criteria

Tags: android, gridview, custom-controls

[image]

I am having requirement of **custom gridview** like above image. My problem is that there will be some tags, and on basis of its value, dynamically row will be added in existing gridview (in below case, row no. 5,8,9). I am stuck at this point and dont know how should i achieve this ? I am not sure whether gridview is a suitable control for this purpose or not.

Any help or guidance will be really appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Binded data in normal gridview. But now how to proceed towards adding rows like 5,8,9, that i am not getting. Seeking help for that.

Comment: Do you want to add that rows at specific positions dynamically?

Comment: Row is added dynamically, but position will not be fixed. It is like, I am getting my data to bind with gridview. Then I will check each data. If i found particular tag attached with that data, then at that position, row like 5th number should be added.

Comment: Use a `ListView` with two types of rows.

Comment: @Luksprog two types of rows means ?

Comment: One type of row which is a normal `ListView` row, one that fills the entire width(rows 5, 8, 9 in your drawing). Another type of row which you make to look as being two items(with a `LinearLayout` that equally divides its two children), in your drawing this would be rows containing (1,2), (3, 4) and (6, 7). Of course you'll need to implement some sort of logic to translate the click event from the `ListView` row to the actual data that it represents.

Comment: but how the data can be loaded in needed way ?